# Unable to include salesforce base url in email html body

Tags: apex, html, singleemailmessage

I have been trying to include Salesforce base URL along with some static information in the html body of the email but to no luck. I keep getting error "Error: Compile Error: Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.".

I have even tried to put all the information between the html tags, but that too din't helped.

```
    String body='';

    body += '<html></br> </br>' + 'For more details, please review the Case HERE: '+ 
    <a href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/'+instOfCase.id+'">'+instOfCase.CaseNumber+'</a>
    body +=  '</body></html>';

    mail.setHtmlBody(body);
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: Instead of this ->"'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl()+'/',,,,,try this
"'" + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl() + "'/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just doing the exact same thing today. Do it like this...

```
String body='';

body += '<html></br> </br>' + 'For more details, '
     + 'please review the Case HERE: '
     + '<a href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
     + '/' + instOfCase.id + '">' + instOfCase.CaseNumber 
     + '</a>';
body +=  '</body></html>';

mail.setHtmlBody(body);
```

Use

```
.toExternalForm()
```

to put this as a String in your URL  - This will work for you!

Please see the Docs [HERE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm) for future reference.

Happy coding!